# Retrieve a value from a table in a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

From a view, I push a tableView where the back button is hidden.
When one row is selected, the "back button" appear.
I would like to pass to the value of the selected row as the user tap on the back button as content of a textField.

This is the code of the tableView (CategoryListController.m):

```
-(NSString *)ritornaValore {
    return valoreCategoria;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [categoryListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    valoreCategoria = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"key"];
    [self ritornaValore];
}
```

valoreCategoria is a NSString declared in the .h

In AddItemController i have this "categoryNameField" where i would like to put inside the value of "valoreCategoria"

```
categoryNameField.text = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before pushing `CategoryListController` from `AddItemController` you should save reference (i.e. `categoryController`) to category list controller.

In `viewWillAppear` of `AddItemController` you should check if `categoryController != nil`. If it is not nil, then you can try to retrieve value : `categoryNameField.text = [categoryController ritornaValore];`. And if you don't need anymore `categoryController` then you should release it `self.categoryController = nil;`.

Check that `categoryController` is defined as `@property (nonatomic, retain) CategoryListController *categoryController;` and `valoreCategoria` as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *valoreCategoria;`.

Comment: I've done as you told, but the "if" condition is never passed. categoryController is always "nil".

Comment: Do you set it after alloc+init?

Comment: Do you mean like this '- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    categoryController = [[CategoryListController alloc] init];
    if (categoryController != nil) {
        categoryNameField.text = [categoryController ritornaValore];
    }
    categoryController = nil;
}'

Comment: Ok, i fixed it! At the end I used a NSString variable declared in CategoryListController.m instead of "valoreCategoria". Thanks a lot for your help.